# Compare two lists in Python

Tags: python, list, compare, beautifulsoup

So here is my code I am trying to compare. What I am trying to do is list the appids out of the path directory, which works. Then I am trying to go out to a website (f). And parse the html page and obtain the appids listed on that site.

What I want to be able to do is take appid from the local system, search f (app ids from the site), and return what the appid is.

When I print appid:

```
D:\python>jump_me.py |more
1b4dd67f29cb1962
28c8b86deab549a1
431a5b43435cc60b
4975d6798a8bdf66
7e4dca80246863e3
8eafbd04ec8631
9b9cdc69c1c24e2b
bc03160ee1a59fc1
```

When I print f, which is the parsed data from online I get:

```
65009083bfa6a094 | (app launched via XPMode) |
469e4a7982cea4d4 | ? (.job) |
b0459de4674aab56 | (.vmcx) |
89b0d939f117f75c | Adobe Acrobat 9 Pro Extended (32-bit) |
26717493b25aa6e1 | Adobe Dreamweaver CS5 (32-bit) |
e2a593822e01aed3 | Adobe Flash CS5 (32-bit) |
c765823d986857ba | Adobe Illustrator CS5 (32-bit) |
84f066768a22cc4f | Adobe Photoshop CS5 (64-bit) |
44a398496acc926d | Adobe Premiere Pro CS5 (64-bit) |
```

I want to compare appid with f, and print the corresponding item:

Like appid = `89b0d939f117f75c`

```
f = 89b0d939f117f75c | Adobe Acrobat 9 Pro Extended (32-bit)
```

So I would want it to return, `89b0d939f117f75c | Adobe Acrobat 9 Pro Extended (32-bit)` based on the directory listing.

Make sense?

----code----

```
import os
import sys
import urllib2
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

path = ("C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Recent\AutomaticDestinations")
for ids in os.listdir(path):
appid = "%s" % (ids).rstrip('.automaticDestinations-ms')
#print appid

f = urllib2.urlopen("http://www.forensicswiki.org/wiki/List_of_Jump_List_IDs")
s = f.read()

soup = BeautifulSoup(''.join(s))
rows = soup.findAll('tr')

for tr in rows:

    cols = tr.findAll('td', limit=2)
    for td in cols:
        text = ''.join(td.findAll(text=True))

        print text + " |",
    print "\n".strip()
f.close
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to do something like:

```
if appid == td.split('|')[0].strip():
    print td
```

I think. But it's unclear to me where any of the data actually is: your example retrieved data doesn't match what you're doing with BeautifulSoup: that `td` is maybe the wrong place to be checking.

The point though is that you need to be comparing `appid` with some substring of the text you're searching through. You're not doing *any* comparisons, though, so I don't have any idea where you should be putting it.

Answer (score 1):

Make dictionary from f and use appid as a key.